# I have a centos server and I am trying to monitor memory via snmp but didnot got the actual result

Tags: centos, snmp, oid

I have a centos server and I am trying to monitor memory but didnot got the actual result. I have used Snmpwalk and used the oid of the used memory but it is returning me the value that is not matched to any parameter. The server is hosted inside esxi.
I have used the command:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c test@123 10.10.0.120 .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6.0
```

this command should provide me used memory but i am getting the value of something else. The result I got is:

```
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memAvailReal.0 = INTEGER: 5315584 kB

            total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.6Gi       1.5Gi       5.1Gi       113Mi       1.0Gi       5.7Gi
Swap:         5.0Gi          0B       5.0Gi
```

In the output the used is 1.5Gi but the output of snmpwalk is around 5.3Gi.

Is there any way i can get the oid of the free, used and available memory. Or is there any way we can list UCD-SNMP-MIB::memAvailReal.0 and its corresponding oid.

Comment: Run `free` _without_ `-h`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to snmpwalk the entire tree `1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4` ?

You will get a clear overview of the possible snmp return.
Check [this link](https://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4) to have the description of the tree.